# JAR launches fine when run through Terminal, but not when double-clicked

Tags: java, file, jar

So I'm trying to load a file using a jar. The file is **outside** of the jar, but in the same folder. When I run the jar form the terminal using java -jar Test.jar it works just fine, but if I run it by double clicking the jar it does not *correctly* load from the file. I can load external Images just fine with either method, but not a file I have created. This is running on Mac OSX. This problem also seems to exist on Ubuntu. On Windows, however, the File is loaded even more incorrectly.

The Path loaded from seems to be the same for both cases. When running from terminal, the output for numbers is correct. However, when running by double clicking, any number over 127 is loaded improperly. I have researched for hours for a solution, with no avail.

EDIT: This is my manifest

```
Main-Class: Test
```

I have created this simple application to demonstrate my problem.

This is what writes the file that will be read.

```
import java.io.*;

public class TestWriter{
public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
        // Create the file and FileWriter.
        FileWriter out = new FileWriter(new File("test.map"));

        // Write some test numbers.
        for (int i = 0; i < 481; i += 30)
            out.write(i);

        // Flush the output (for good measure?)
        out.flush();

        // Close the output.
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

This is what loads the file.

```
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

public class Run extends JComponent{

// Image to be drawn on screen
BufferedImage IMAGE;

// Output to be drawn on screen
String string = "";


// Loading a MAP file - includes loading a bmp image and a .map (txt file).
public Run(){

    // MAP name
    String map = "test";
    System.out.println("Loading map: "+map);

    // Get path
    String path = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();

    String decodedPath = "";

    // Decode path
    try{
        decodedPath = URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8");
        decodedPath = decodedPath.substring(0, decodedPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Could not decode path.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }

    // Add decoded path to output string
    string += decodedPath;


    try{
        IMAGE = ImageIO.read(new File(decodedPath+"/"+map+".bmp"));
        System.out.println("MAP image loaded.");
    } catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Could not load MAP image.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }

    try{
        System.out.println("Loading MAP data.");
        // Create a new reader
        FileReader in = new FileReader(new File(decodedPath+"/"+map+".map"));

        // While there is something left to be read
        while (in.ready()){
            // add the next input to the output string
            string += ", "+in.read();
        }

        // Close the input (for good measure)
        in.close();
        System.out.println("Loaded MAP data.");

    } catch (Exception e){
        System.err.println("Could not load MAP data.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }

    // Repaint the screen to show our newly loaded image and string
    repaint();
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(IMAGE,0,0,null);
    g.drawString(string,16,64);
}
}
```

This is the main method that creates the JFrame and adds the component Run()

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class Test{
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("\nInitializing...");
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");

    int frameWidth = 640;
    int frameHeight = 200;
    frame.setSize(frameWidth,frameHeight);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocation(240,60);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new Run());
    frame.setVisible(true);

    System.out.println("Running...");
}
}
```

Comment: I am creating the jar using the terminal, using

jar cvfm Test.jar manifest.txt *.class

Do I need to do something differently?

Comment: What do you mean by any number over 127 is loaded improperly? How so?

Comment: It is loaded in as a maxed short (65535)